# Populate and Update Form data in ColdFusion

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I have a form the needs to be populated and and updated.  There are several dropdown fields and input fields on the form that need to be populated and then allow the user to make a change if necessary. I have created queries to select the data, then I want to populate the form with the selected data but, allow a user to change the form fields. I have tried with the first field which is a dropdown field but, I receive an error saying that I can't nest two queries.

This is the error I received: A query driven cfoutput tag is nested inside a cfoutput tag that also has a query attribute. This is not allowed. Nesting these tags implies that you want to use grouped processing. However, only the top-level tag can specify the query that drives the processing.

Here is my code:

```
<cfoutput query="getinfo">
  <select name="ProgramName" id="ProgramName" style= "font-size:24px">
    <option style="font-size:24px" value = "0">--Program Name--</option>
    <cfloop query="PName">
      <option value="#ProgramName#">#ProgramName#</option>
    </cfloop>   
  </select>
</cfoutput>
```

Here is my getinfo query:

```
<cfquery name="getinfo" datasource="dbotest">
    SELECT  ProgramName, TestName
      FROM  Programs
     WHERE  ProgramID = "D219"      
</cfquery>
```

Comment: that code is perfectly valid. Did you have `<cfoutput>` tags with your pname query originally?

Comment: Dang it @MattBusche, you beat me again. ;)  John - is there another `<cfoutput>` tag surrounding the code you have given that we cannot see?

Comment: That code on it's own will not produce the error you got.  By the way, if query getinfo has more than one row, you will be getting a series of dropdowns, all with the same name, and all with the same available options.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I would also HIGHLY suggest scoping your variables. The code you've posted seems to only be using the data from `PName`. What is the `getinfo` query used for?

Comment: @MattBusche I did not have <cfoutput> tags with my pname query.  I will put the tags around the query and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnBumbray, adding cfoutput tags will make it worse.  Is the code you posted inside an existing cfoutput block?

Comment: @JohnBumbray Can you post your full code block? I put together an answer that shows valid and invalid syntax for outputting data.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted is valid syntax for outputting a query.

```
<cfoutput query="getinfo">
  <select name="ProgramName" id="ProgramName" style= "font-size:24px">
    <option style="font-size:24px" value = "0">--Program Name--</option>
    <cfloop query="PName">
      <option value="#ProgramName#">#ProgramName#</option>
    </cfloop>   
  </select>
</cfoutput>
```

If your page is set up like this, then that is invalid. You can simply change `<cfoutput query="getinfo">` to be `<cfloop query="getinfo">`

```
<cfoutput>
<!--- other code --->
<cfloop query="getinfo">
  <select name="ProgramName" id="ProgramName" style= "font-size:24px">
    <option style="font-size:24px" value = "0">--Program Name--</option>
    <cfloop query="PName">
      <option value="#ProgramName#">#ProgramName#</option>
    </cfloop>   
  </select>
</cfloop>
<!--- more code --->
</cfoutput>
```

(I know this isn't really an *answer* but should hopefully help clear things up.)

Comment: But you didn't change it yourself.  Was that a mistake?